# Repeat a task after exact n Millisecond in android

Tags: android, timer

My requirement is to sample android sensor data after every *n* millisecond exact.

Tried using `timer` , `alarmManager` and `handler`. The task getting repeated but the duration is not exact *n* millisecond.

Code::

Handle:

```
Handler sensorHandler = new Handler();
    private Runnable sensorRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            sendAllSensorData();
            sensorHandler.postDelayed(sensorRunnable, 50);
        }
    };

    private void postSensorMsgHandler() {
        sensorHandler.postDelayed(sensorRunnable, 50);
    }
```

Timer ::
private void initTimer() {

timer = new Timer();

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        sendAllSensorData();
    }
}, TelemetricConstant.delay, TelemetricConstant.SAMPLE_PERIOD);
```

}

Logs::

```
06-22 15:34:53.201 D/Telemetric(27434): Telemetric Gyroscope Y mean = -0.000533 sd = 0.000958 variance = 0.000001

06-22 15:34:53.212 D/Telemetric(27434): Telemetric Gyroscope Y mean = 0.001057 sd = 0.000000 variance = 0.000000

06-22 15:34:53.253 D/Telemetric(27434): Telemetric Gyroscope Y mean = 0.000524 sd = 0.000754 variance = 0.000001

06-22 15:34:53.264 D/Telemetric(27434): Telemetric Gyroscope Y mean = -0.000009 sd = 0.001066 variance = 0.000001

06-22 15:34:53.306 D/Telemetric(27434): Telemetric Gyroscope Y mean = 0.000524 sd = 0.001376 variance = 0.000002

06-22 15:34:53.317 D/Telemetric(27434): Telemetric Gyroscope Y mean = 0.000844 sd = 0.001390 variance = 0.000002

06-22 15:34:53.361 D/Telemetric(27434): Telemetric Gyroscope Y mean = 0.000702 sd = 0.001291 variance = 0.000002

06-22 15:34:53.370 D/Telemetric(27434): Telemetric Gyroscope Y mean = 0.000600 sd = 0.001209 variance = 0.000001

06-22 15:34:53.414 D/Telemetric(27434): Telemetric Gyroscope Y mean = 0.000391 sd = 0.001266 variance = 0.000002

06-22 15:34:53.423 D/Telemetric(27434): Telemetric Gyroscope Y mean = 0.000465 sd = 0.001205 variance = 0.000001
```

Comment: if you want some `Runnable` to be run at some exact time use `Handler#postAtTime` method

Comment: Handler sensorHandler = new Handler();
    private Runnable sensorRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Logger.d("Handler Timer::" + System.currentTimeMillis());
            sendAllSensorData();
            sensorHandler.postAtTime(sensorRunnable,SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 50);
        }
    };

    private void postSensorMsgHandler() {
        sensorHandler.postAtTime(sensorRunnable, SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 50);
    }

This is my code for postAtTime. Same result
Handler Timer::1498126539758
Handler Timer::1498126539782

Comment: what `long uptimeMillis` value are you passing to `postAtTime`?

Comment: uptimeMillis  is counted in milliseconds since the system was booted.

Comment: i mean what **exact** value are you passing and when your `Runnable` is run, what is the difference of those two timestamps?

Comment: I am just adding 50 ms to current uptime. And telling to run the task after 50ms from now.  Is anything wrong.

Comment: i know what you are doing, since i see the code, what i dont know is the **EXACT** value of `long uptimeMillis` parameter passed to `postAtTime` method and how this timestamp differ from the time when your `Runnable` is called by the system

Answer (score 2):

try this ,

```
//Create Timer Object 
Timer t = new Timer();
//Set your schedule time
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Called each time when 1000 milliseconds (1 second)
    }

},
//Set start timing (milliseconds)
0,
//Set interval time(milliseconds)
1000);
```

Comment: Thanks Manoj for the answer, My use case is intent   to millisecond granularity.  if i use 1 sec then it works fine. Any idea ??

Comment: Ok means its not working in milliseconds ? Can u please try this code this and placed milliseconds.

Comment: Code i paste with question has timer task where TelemetricConstant.delay is 0 and TelemetricConstant.SAMPLE_PERIOD is 50.

Answer (score 0):

Android is not a "real-time operating system" to get the great accuracy you're looking for you would probably need another hardware for example some Embedded like Raspberry  ...  and another operating system, for example some "RealTime Linux"
https://www.socallinuxexpo.org/sites/default/files/presentations/Steven_Doran_SCALE_13x.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use regular sensor polling mechanism of the Android framework?

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#registerListener(android.hardware.SensorEventListener,%20android.hardware.Sensor,%20int)

Comment: samplingPeriodUs  parameter in registerListener  doesn't guarantee exact time. It just a hint to system as per document.

Tried this one. Same result.

samplingPeriodUs int: The desired delay between two consecutive events in microseconds. This is only a hint to the system. Events may be received faster or slower than the specified rate. Usually events are received faster

Comment: You can't expect any of the frameworks timers to have less than 16ms granularity, actually, you can't even expect that those timers will keep same intervals for same parameters (which they may keep statistically close to the parameter in the long run). If you REALLY need precise timing -- go native and use platforms hardware timers. It's already said, that Android is not a real-time system, and it tries to optimise performance and power consumption by batching work to be done by multiple apps/threads without switching power levels of the hardware too much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use approach like that: do your work in a loop of thread `run()` method and calculate it's duration (say `workDuration`), than sleep for time `50000000 - workDuration` (where 50000000 is 50 milliseconds in nanos) and continue loop:

```
...
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                long startTime = System.nanoTime();

                // do your work here

                long workEndTime = System.nanoTime();
                long workDuration = workEndTime - startTime;
                long timeToSleep = 50000000 - workDuration;
                long timeToSleepMillis = timeToSleep / 1000000;
                int timeToSleepNanos = (int) (timeToSleep % 1000000);
                Thread.sleep(timeToSleepMillis, timeToSleepNanos);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}).start();
...
```

Of course task getting repeated with duration not exact *n* millisecond, but very close to *n* (it depends on current device). Also you can slightly adjust `timeToSleep` value for more precise sleep duration.